# how do I create the URL "m.mysite.com" from mysite.com?

Tags: directory-structure, subdirectory

I believe a subdirectory would be mysite.com/m/index.htm. I would like the "m" at the front so as to appear "m.mysite.com".

What do I call that type of directory?

I currently have a stylesheet for mobile and it just sits in my root directory and is used with a media query when someone with a small screen visits my site. The mobile optimized sheet uses the main index.htm page.

How would I change the folders in my directory to show "m.mysite.com" when someone is visiting from mobile?

Comment: That is a subdomain, not any kind of directory. How to set up a subdomain very much depends on your hosting situation.

Comment: Thanks. Half of my question was understanding what to ask for - so it's a sub domain, not directory that I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a directory at all. First you need to add a DNS entry for m.example.com, then you need to configure your web server software to serve requests to that host name from the directory you wish.

How you do that depends on your host, your web serving software and how easily you can reconfigure things. It's a bunch of combinations and you haven't given anywhere near enough detail for anyone to answer.

Comment: OK, I'll do some more research